# Call one component in another in NativeScript angular template

Tags: angular2-nativescript

I m creating an nativecript app in angular architecture. So what I wanna do is call a component into another component.

app.component.html...

```
<StackLayout>
<ActionBar title="My App" class="action-bar"></ActionBar>
<Label text='hello world'></Label>
<button text="Click" (tap)="test()"></button>
<test></test> // Its a component
</StackLayout>
```

I had declared that Test component in app.module [declarations].

But app does not run, its prompts an error of Maximum call stack exceeds.

Please tell me where m i going wrong

Comment: can you provide more details

Comment: I didnt know what happened, just changed the name of component and everything worked fine.